# Как осуществить выбор ID таблицы, манипулируя в другой таблице одинаковыми полями этих таблиц

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Есть таблица1 - REF_DEVICE в которой есть ID и SERIAL_NUMBER

Есть таблица 2 - LISTCODE в которой есть DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER(Такой-же как SERIAL_NUMBER в REF_DEVICE)

Как получить ID из REF_DEVICE зная только DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER и о существовании REF_DEVICE и что SERIAL_NUMBER такой-же как DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER?

```
CREATE TABLE REF_DEVICE 
(
  ID              NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL,
  SERIAL_NUMBER   NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  NAME            NVARCHAR2(50),
  DESCRIPTION     NVARCHAR2(150),
  CONSTRAINT PK_REF_DEVICE_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT KEY_REF_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER UNIQUE (SERIAL_NUMBER)
)

CREATE TABLE LISTCODE (
  ID                   NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL,
  DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_LISTCODE_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT KEY_LISTCODE UNIQUE (DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER)
)
```

Пробовал забрать так. Не работает

```
SELECT ID
FROM REF_DEVICE
WHERE REF_DEVICE.SERIAL_NUMBER = LISTCODE.DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER
```

Comment: JOIN вас спасет

Comment: @aepot, я гуглил про джоин но так и не понял как им пользоваться. Поэтому и задал сюда вопрос, я только изучаю как работают SQL запросы. Если вы сможете написать код для подобного. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Да не нужен тут JOIN. И вторая таблица не нужна. Обычный WHERE.

Comment: @Akina А как? Не пойму, типа `SELECT id FROM таблица1 WHERE таблица2.Device_Num == таблица2.Device_Num`, так??

Comment: Это вопрос по sql или по c# entity framework?

Comment: @bubadev SQL запрос в ораклДБ, при помощи C# .net6

Comment: зачем вообще тут join , если он знает конкретный serial_number? просто: SELECT D.ID
FROM REF_DEVICE D
WHERE D.SERIAL_NUMBER = '1234567890' /*свой серийник впишите*/

Comment: @Konst я не знаю конкретный серийник. Необходимо осуществить выборку. из данных из таблицы листкод и подставить ID за место device_secial_number

Comment: в вопросе у вас было другое требование. вы можете уточнить, что вам надо получить в выборке и из каких таблиц. вот пример выборки всех девайсов , серийники которых присутствуют в табличке LISTCODE: SELECT D.ID, D.SERIAL_NUMBER, D.NAME, D.DESCRIPTION
FROM REF_DEVICE D
WHERE 
 EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LISTCODE L WHERE L.DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER = D.SERIAL_NUMBER)

Comment: @Konst не понимаю как работает ваш код, да и он не работает. Пишет ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement. 
Может, я неправильно описываю проблему. Мне недо получить ID. из таблицы 1, обращаясь к таблице 2, зная что в таблице 1 и 2 есть поля с одинаковыми значениями

Comment: Я написал примерный код того, как должно получится. Я хочу получить ID из таблицы REF_DEVICE в переменную, при условии совпадения серийников в обеих таблицах

Comment: SELECT D.ID FROM REF_DEVICE AS D INNER JOIN LISTCODE AS L ON D.SERIAL_NUMBER = L.DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER

Comment: @Konst https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=051e27496dd7f8d7bef23cf20c5bd7f7

Comment: вы уж сами можете синтаксис конкретного средства проверки подставить: SELECT 
     D.ID 
FROM REF_DEVICE D INNER JOIN LISTCODE L 
     ON D.SERIAL_NUMBER = L.DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER
/  Добавьте данные в таблицы и получите результат

Comment: @Konst Я не понимаю откуда берутся D и L что они значат и где можно про них почитать?)

Comment: это алиасы ваших таблиц, можно и без них, но с ними проще и не запутаешься: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d51907a9df881f287161406330cc0930

Comment: @Konst тоесть это делается чтобы не писать тут 'D.SERIAL_NUMBER = L.DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER' полные имена таблиц? Круто, спасибо!) И да этот комментарий решает вопрос. Напишите его, пожалуйста, в форме ответа)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE REF_DEVICE 
(
  ID              NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL,
  SERIAL_NUMBER   NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  NAME            NVARCHAR2(50),
  DESCRIPTION     NVARCHAR2(150),
  CONSTRAINT PK_REF_DEVICE_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT KEY_REF_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER UNIQUE (SERIAL_NUMBER)
)
/
CREATE TABLE LISTCODE (
  ID                   NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL,
  DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_LISTCODE_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT KEY_LISTCODE UNIQUE (DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER)
)
/
INSERT INTO REF_DEVICE (ID, SERIAL_NUMBER) VALUES (1, '1234')
/
INSERT INTO LISTCODE (ID, DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER) VALUES (1, '1234')
/
SELECT 
     D.ID 
FROM REF_DEVICE D INNER JOIN LISTCODE L 
     ON D.SERIAL_NUMBER = L.DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER
/
```